# sending a message from a service to different app using aidl

Tags: android, ipc, aidl

I have two apps, app A and app B.

A is just a service , which starts on BOOT COMPLETE and restarts if destroyed.

A constantly receives messages(through serial connection, but that's irrelevant).

If a message is received but no other apps are bound to the service , I don't care about the message and it can be lost.

However , if some message is received and let's say B is bound to it, I want B to receive that message.

So , I tried using AIDL to pass the message from A to B , but I can't get it to work . I'm probably not doing something right here or not using it correctly, so I will appreciate any help here.

my code in my service :

```
public class ExtProtocolService extends Service {
static RS232Comm serialComm;
public static final int BAUDRATE = 19200;
public static final int COM = 1;
public static Handler handler;
private Message message;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return (new MessageBinder());
}

private static class MessageBinder extends IExtMessage.Stub {

    @Override
    public void receive(IExtMessageCallBack callback) {
        new ReceiveThread(callback).
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    serialComm = new RS232Comm(COM, BAUDRATE, 0, this);

    handler=new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            message=msg;
        }
    };


}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Protocol Service Started",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return START_STICKY;
}

public static class ReceiveThread implements Runnable {
    int numCharsToRead = 2;
    IExtMessageCallBack cb = null;
    boolean ok;

    ReceiveThread(IExtMessageCallBack cb) {
        this.cb = cb;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            serialComm.Open();
            ok = serialComm.Receive(numCharsToRead);
            if (ok) {
                cb.onSuccess();
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

}
```

**RS232Comm serialComm** is a class in which i'm receiving my messages , the main code there  :

```
                    Message message=Message.obtain();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("command", command);
                bundle.putInt("messageLength", messageLength);
                bundle.putString("wholeData", wholeData);
                message.setData(bundle);
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ExtProtocolService.handler.sendMessage(message);
                return true;
```

As you can see i'm using a handler to pass the message back to the service class.

my AIDL files are:

```
interface IExtMessage{
void receive(IExtMessageCallBack callback);
  }
```

and :

```
interface IExtMessageCallBack{

void onSuccess();
void onFailure(String msg);

}
```

Now, app B , it's just a main activity to test if my message is passed:

```
package com.tfl.testmyservice;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection {
    public static final String TAG = "YANIV";
    private IExtMessage binding;
    private Application appContext = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent implicit = new Intent(IExtMessage.class.getName());
        List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(
                implicit, 0);

        if (matches.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Cannot find a matching service!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else if (matches.size() > 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Found multiple matching services!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Intent explicit = new Intent(implicit);
            ServiceInfo svcInfo = matches.get(0).serviceInfo;
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(
                    svcInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, svcInfo.name);
            explicit.setComponent(cn);
            bindService(explicit, this, Context.BIND_WAIVE_PRIORITY);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        binding = IExtMessage.Stub.asInterface(binder);

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        binding = null;

    }

    public void onEventMainTread(CallbackEvent event){
        if(event.succeeded){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, event.msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    IExtMessageCallBack.Stub cb=new IExtMessageCallBack.Stub() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() throws RemoteException {
            new CallbackEvent(true, null);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String msg) throws RemoteException {
            new CallbackEvent(false, msg);

        }
    };


    static class CallbackEvent{
        boolean succeeded=false;
        String msg=null;

        public CallbackEvent(boolean succeeded,String msg) {
            this.succeeded=succeeded;
            this.msg=msg;
        }

    }


}
```

Same AIDL are also in app B.

the output that i'm getting is "no services matching found!"

just want to point out that the service on itself is working great. just when I'm trying this IPC using AIDL things get a little messy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your action string for the service in MainActivity is not normal.

You are using the class name of `IExtMessage` as service action string.

```
Intent implicit = new Intent(IExtMessage.class.getName());
List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(implicit, 0);
```

But normally a string related to service itself is used for action string, not related to IPC classes.

You'd better double check the action string in intent filter of service `ExtProtocolService` in  App A's android manifest file. You should use same string with that in querying intent.

And also check if the service is 'exported' in manifest file.